# Using static field in preference screen xml

Tags: android, xml, preferenceactivity

Is it possible to use static field in xml?

"customerId" from code

```
public class Const {

    public static final String EXTRA_CUSTOMER_ID = "customerId";
}
```

in preferences xml as key name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/setup">
        <EditTextPreference android:key="customerId" android:summary="..."      android:title="@string/lb_customer_id" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to save Strings in this constants you can use the file "res/values/strings.xml".

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="lb_customer_id">customerId</string>
</resources>
```

to get one string of strings.xml you have to use the method:

```
getString(R.strings.lb_customer_id).
```

hope it helps.

Comment: yes, a know that way, but the question about to change "customerId" in EditTextPreference key by static constant. it looks more aesthetically pleasing, in my opinion and easier to write code